# List Source Control Files and Folder under a given TFS Path (without work-space mapping)

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm redesigning a control that lists the contents (files and folders) under a given TFS path. The tricky part is that I don't want to create a workspace for achieving this, as my intention is just to list the contents and display the history of a selected item. The current implementation creates a local workspace mapping in the background to achieve this, is this needed? Can I attain this without a local workspace mapping?

Thanks 
Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GetItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getitems.aspx), which does not require a workspace.  For example:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");   
VersionControlServer versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();   
ItemSet items = versionControl.GetItems(tfsPath, RecursionType.Full);
```