# VSTS SDK retrieve projects in subfolders

Tags: tfs

I have the following code to retrieve all projects in TFS using the .net SDK for VSTS and using TFS2018. But I only get the top most project folders. How can I retrieve the subfolders of a certain project?

```
var uri = new Uri("https://devserver/tfs/DefaultCollection");
using (var projectHttpClient = new ProjectHttpClient(uri, cred))                    {
    var projects = projectHttpClient.GetProjects().Result;
}
```

I also tried changing the uri to

```
var uri = new Uri("https://devserver/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject");
```

But I get a Page not found error.

Here is a snapshot of the TFS structure. I would like to retrieve the projects on the sublevel. However I am only receiving the second level projects. The level with the user icons.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "subfolders of a project"? There is no such thing. Are you talking about the Teams within a team project?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann see the upadted answer...

Comment: Those aren't projects. Those are folders in source control. You need to use the Version Control client.

Comment: This is actually what I needed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505190/list-source-control-files-and-folder-under-a-given-tfs-path-without-work-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below to get folders:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TestCaseProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
            var versioncontrols = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            var workspace = versioncontrols.CreateWorkspace("workspaceName","workspaceOwner");

            String ServerFolder = @"$/TeamProject/Folder";
            String LocalFolder = @"C:\Folder";

            WorkingFolder workfolder = new WorkingFolder(ServerFolder, LocalFolder);
            workspace.CreateMapping(workfolder);

            workspace.Get();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a way what I needed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505190/list-source-control-files-and-folder-under-a-given-tfs-path-without-work-space